# WPF: Get underlying element inside adorner in PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown of a Canvas

Tags: wpf, event-handling, adorner

Canvas has element with adorner. Adorner uses VisualCollection, and places a thumb to specific place of the adorned element. I would like to click to the adorner, hanlde PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event of the canvas and get the underlying element inside the adorner. But I get MainWindow as e.Source in this case. Could you please help? I'm almost newbie in WPF.

```
public class ConnectorAdorner : Adorner
{
    private readonly ConnectorThumb _thumb;
    private readonly VisualCollection _visuals;

    public ConnectorAdorner(UIElement adornedElement) : base(adornedElement)
    {
        Focusable = true;
        _visuals = new VisualCollection(this);
        _thumb = new ConnectorThumb();
        _thumb.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
        _visuals.Add(_thumb);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        double elHeight = AdornedElement.DesiredSize.Height;
        double adornerWidth = DesiredSize.Width;
        double adornerHeight = DesiredSize.Height;
        _thumb.Arrange(new Rect(0, -elHeight/2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));
        return finalSize;
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return _visuals[index];
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get { return _visuals.Count; }
    }
}

public class Shape : UserControl
{
    private AdornerLayer _adornerLayer;

    public Shape()
    {
        Width = 50;
        Height = 50;
        Background = Brushes.Tomato;
        BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
        BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
        this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        _adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this);
        if (_adornerLayer != null)
        {
            ConnectorAdorner adorner = new ConnectorAdorner(this);
            _adornerLayer.Add(adorner);
        }
    }
}

public class ConnectorThumb : Thumb
{
    public ConnectorThumb()
    {
        Width = 20;
        Height = 20;
        Background = Brushes.Transparent;
        Foreground = Brushes.Black;
        BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
        IsHitTestVisible = true;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // I'd like to get ConnectionThumb here..
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you use `e.Source`?

Comment: Sorry, I get MainWindow, not Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

While it is hard to say without seeing your code, but I think using the `Canvas.ZIndex` property on the elements (Adorner) will ensure that the elements are layered the way your want.